# Use nuget package without publishing

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I create my own nuget package and now I need to use it in all my projects in the solution. But I do not want to publish it on nuget.org. Probably it's possible to put it into folder next to my .sln file?
I've already created nuget.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="dependencyVersion" value="Highest" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MySource" value="..\MyPackages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

and my .csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyPackage1234" Version="*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

But I receive this error instantly:
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   NU1101  Unable to find package MyPackage1234. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a folder on your machine and use it as a local source of packages. You can build it locally, and put it in that folder.

Go to Tools --> Options --> Nuget, and find the bit that lets you control your package sources, and add a new source, pointing to your local folder.

This will allow you to test your package locally, and build locally.

Comment: But if I want to share my project with the team? It would be better to specify a folder of the solution in .csproj file or in nuget.config.

Comment: In regards to sharing with a team use  a network file share as per Microsoft documentation [Hosting your own NuGet feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) which is in short the same as Ian's recommendation just on a network or (as in the link above) a NuGet hosting product.